# Expand string of one cell into two cells

Tags: excel

I m trying to find how to expand a string of one cell to be shown in two or more cells without merging them.

Any help will appreciate?

Comment: Can you give an example of what this should look like? By default, if the content of a cell exceeds its boundaries, it'll be displayed in an adjacent blank cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

> Select and right-click the cells in question -> Format Cells ->
>   Alignment -> Set Horizontal to: Center Across Selection